# How to split an array from a text file by a comma, only getting one array index displayed in Listbox?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, listbox

First of all I would like to thank anyone willing to help ahead of time. My issue here is that when I attempt to populate my listbox with items in my array, I am getting only "General" added as a listbox item instead of the actual strings in the array. I'm rather new to programming so I apologize if this is an obvious error in my code, although I'm assuming it probably is.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub frmSalesSummary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
MyBase.Load
    Dim info() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("info.txt")
    Dim splitChar As Char = ","
    Dim infoString As String
    For i = 0 To info.GetUpperBound(0)
        infoString = info(i).Split(splitChar)
        lstSummary.Items.Add(infoString(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

The text file contains this for testing "alex,General,7,$105.00" on the first line.

There may be frequent edits to this question as I am actively trying to figure this out myself as well. Apologies.

Comment: so are you wanting the name in the listbox (ie, alex)? Because if that's the case you would want to add infoString(0) with each iteration. Also, probably a typo but infoString needs to be an array.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, how do you mean add infoString(0)? In the loop? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, yes I would like the name in the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'info' is your line (comma delimited)
'infoString' is an array of the words that are separated by the Split

So if you want to add a single item from that split you would use
infoString(0) for the name, infoString(1) for the Rank, etc...

So you're taking each line, splitting it and to add the name to the listbox you only need to add infoString(0) because that element of the array holds the name from splitting it out from the line.

Try

```
lstSummary.Items.Add(infoString(0))
```

If you're wanting a list like:

```
alex
General
7
$105.00
```

You could create another loop inside your current loop and use the iterator for the index.

```
For i = 0 to info.GetUpperbound(0)
   infoString = info(i).Split(splitChar)
   For x = 0 to infoString.GetUpperBound(0)
      lstSummary.Items.Add(infoString(x))
   Next
Next
```

This would take each Line, split it and then add the info from each line to the listbox... Keep in mind, you would have the 4 you showed, then the next line would put the next 4 pieces of information until you run out of lines in your text file.

Still not quite sure if that is exactly what you're trying to do, if this still isn't the case, you might mock up some picture of what you're expecting along with information as to whether or not there is more of this information in the text file.

Comment: Thank you, so if I wanted to list all of them separately I would just use lstSummary(infoString(1)), lstSummary.Items.Add(infoString(2)), etc.?

Comment: So you're wanting the listbox to hold the 4 pieces of information?

Comment: Yeah, that's the case, apologies for lack of clarification.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Appreciate you to the ends of the earth!

Answer (score 0):

A small tip. You should never use controls to store the data you're using. Store it as a list of `PersonDetails` objects, or whatever you want to call them.

You can declare the `PersonDetails` object like this ..

```
Private Class PersonDetails
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Category As String
    Public Property Type As Integer
    Public Property Amount As Decimal
End Class
```

And the list of them like this

```
Dim PersonSummaryList As New List(Of PersonDetails)
```

Your form load event reads the text file and for each line, creates a new `PersonDetails` object and adds it to the list of `PersonDetails` and then adds the names to a ListBox

```
Private Sub frmSalesSummary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim info() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("info.txt")
    Dim splitChar As Char = ","c
    Dim infoString() As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To info.GetUpperBound(0)
        infoString = info(i).Split(splitChar)
        'remove the commas and $ signs
        infoString(3) = infoString(3).Replace("$"c, "")
        Dim newPerson As New PersonDetails
        newPerson.Name = infoString(0)
        newPerson.Category = infoString(1)
        newPerson.Type = Integer.Parse(infoString(2))
        Decimal.TryParse(infoString(3), newPerson.Amount)
        PersonSummaryList.Add(newPerson)
    Next

End Sub
```

In your ListBox, all you will see is a list of names, and when you click on an item, the code below will find the object that matches the name you selected and display whatever properties you want in a MessageBox, but of course you can do whatever you want with the `tempPerson` object.

```
Private Sub LstSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LstSummary.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim tempPerson As PersonDetails = PersonSummaryList.Find(Function(x) x.Name = LstSummary.SelectedItem.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("Name :" & tempPerson.Name & vbCrLf & "Amount :" & tempPerson.Amount)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I appreciate your input, that would definitely be a better programming practice.

Comment: Especially any controls that the user can modify themselves - textboxes etc. :-)